# 2 LED strips in parallel dimmed with PWM

Tags: arduino, led, pwm

If i have 2 LED strips of 10 amps @ 12 volt and I connect them in parallel . Can i run them off a 10 amp transformer if I use a 50% PWM duty cycle ?

I assume that if the PWM is not in sync that the total amps used will be 10 as the 1 strip will be ON while the other is OFF.  But if the PWM is in sync will the total amps be 20 because both is ON and OFF the same time, or does it not matter as amps is a measured Coulomb per second so the total charge moved in 1 second is still 10 amps?

Comment: In the example,if the power supply can't provide the 20A from the decoupling capacitor, can you  add say one to each line to help smooth the load on the transformer ? I would also think that if you buy a transformer with 2 positive and 2 negative connection points that they took this into consideration .

Answer (score 1):

Even if the PWM was in sync, the PWM's on/off speed would need to be above 100 Hz or so for humans **not** to notice the flicker.

Power supplies are **too slow** to respond to this, the power supply will only see the average of the current going to the LEDs.

For this "slowness" not to be a problem (and improve the response to varying current demands from the load) a power supply will have a **decoupling capacitor** at it's output and it is this capacitor which will actually take care of the 20 A pulses your LEDs will be drawing.

Comment: Power supplies are plenty fast to react to PWM signals normally used in displays. These start at around 90Hz and usually taper off around 500Hz. If you're using current mode control, peak current limit may very well kick in and cut the power level or even put the PSU to glitch mode. Granted, if you've got chunky capacitor and fast enough PWM, it'll work the way you described.

Answer (score 0):

Running strings of LEDs in parallel is not recommended especially high wattage LEDs due to the inherent dynamic resistance increasing the probability of thermal runaway.

Use two constant current supplies. e.g. Mean Well HLG-150H-12 @ $45 each or $90.

If you were to run them in parallel you would need a HLG-320-12 @ $95 costing $5 more and you will have an unbalanced load.

I have tested running 2 strips of 16 Luxeon Rebel white in parallel and never did each string carry the same current.

In one test the forward voltages were closely matched at 43.29v and 43.85v.  The vf were measured as soon as they were powered on before they got warm. The currents were 240mA and 135mA when powered with a single CC HLG-60-54B set at 375mA.  Currents were measured after being powered on for 30 minutes.

I also powered them with a CV HEP-185-54A, set at 48v using a 5.1Ω series resistor on each sting.  The currents were 380mA and 270mA.